# compiler warning output backslash and slash ("\ /") in path

Tags: c++, qt

I have a strange problem. My compilerwarnings look like

```
code\/log_event.h:59:16: warning:   'xxxxxx'
code\/log_event.h:58:18: warning:   'xxxxxxxx'
code\log_event.cpp:15:1: warning:    xxxxxxxx
```

The problem is that I use Jenkins Compilerwarning plugin which resolves the paths to the files. And obviously it is not possible to find the correct path to file log_event.h. This is because it parses the compilerwarning and finds a "/". But this only occurs in the header file. Currently I'm using qmake to build.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

edit:

i think i found the problem: qmake genereates a source file with

```
SOURCES = code\log_event.cpp
```

but

```
OBJECTS = test/bin/debug/log_event.o
```

with the wrong slash :(

Comment: Mentioning which compiler you use might be a worthy addition.

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: And you are sure that this "Jenkins Compilerwarning plugin" isn't the culprit?

Comment: `/` is the "right" slash, `\\` is the "wrong" slash (unless you only care about windows).

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Under Unix, `/` is the right "slash".  Under Windows, both `/` and `'\'` are right.  Which one you use is (usually) a matter of personal taste, but... In C/C++ strings, `/` is preferable, since `'\'` is the escape character, and when invoking a program from the command line `'\'` is preferable, since many (most, in fact) programs take `/` as the start of an option.

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the following solution for this problem:

In the .pro file I added "QMAKE_DIR_SEP = /" and now everything works fine under linux and under windows. There is still a mixture of \ and / in the Makefiles generated under Windows, but with this configuration everything compiles AND the output is correct.